Append string along with single quotes to create SQL query?
var
  strng,value,UserName : WideString;
  Query :  Smplquery;
begin
  strng := 'table';
  value := 'column';
    
  Username := 'CN=ABC[EXT] XYZ, AB=HELLO EFG,AB=SDRTY0045,AB=DW,AB=BNKM,HB=SWCD,HB=4QW,HB=PKL';
  Query := CreateSmplquery();
    
  Query.SelectStatement:= format('select * from %s where CONVERT(VARCHAR,%s'+') = (select convert(varchar,%s'+'))',[strng, value, UserName]);
  Query.Run;
end;

On compiling this query in the Delphi IDE, an error occurs as this is creating a query as below:
select *
from table
where CONVERT(VARCHAR,column) = (select convert(varchar,thatCN=ABC[EXT] XYZ, AB=HELLO EFG,AB=SDRTY0045,AB=DW,AB=BNKM,HB=SWCD,HB=4QW,HB=PKL))

How to code it so that I get this SQL query instead?
select *
from table
where CONVERT(VARCHAR,column) = (select convert(varchar,'thatCN=ABC[EXT] XYZ, AB=HELLO EFG,AB=SDRTY0045,AB=DW,AB=BNKM,HB=SWCD,HB=4QW,HB=PKL'))


Matthias B's answer already covers your specific question. I just want to point out that you SHOULD NOT build up SQL statements this way. This is an SQL Injection attack waiting to happen. Always use parameterized queries whenever possible. Let the SQL engine handle any quoting and escaping requirements for you. It is faster and safer that way.

Also, why are you using WideString? Since 2009, you should be using UnicodeString instead.

Also, why are you using CONVERT() in this manner? Why not just compare the column value directly? Query.SelectStatement := Format('select * from %s where %s = %s', [strng, value, QuoteStr(UserName)]);

You just include the ' in the string. To include a ' character in a string, you need to write it twice, that is ''. This is how it needs to look:
Query.SelectStatement:= format('select * from %s where CONVERT(VARCHAR,%s'+') = (select convert(varchar,''%s'''+'))',[strng, value, UserName]);

(You could have made a simpler example.)

But that's a String literal - just like 1337 would be an Integer literal and 3.1415e10 would be a float literal.

Note that this approach will not handle any embedded quotes inside the UserName string value. If you are not careful, malicious input can still cause you to produce bad SQL. You can use QuotedStr() to avoid that, eg: Query.SelectStatement := Format('select * from %s where CONVERT(VARCHAR,%s) = (select convert(varchar,%s))', [strng, value, QuotedStr(UserName)]);
